# Android Emulator UI doesn't respond to input

Tags: android, macos, mobile, android-emulator, emulation

I've just installed the Android SDK (Revision 20.0.3) on my OSX (10.7.4) as I want to run the Android Emulator just to test my web based mobile application using the Android browser.

I downloaded the SDK, ran the package update manager etc, then set up an Android Virtual Device for 2.2 via the GUI and I can successfully start up the emulator, but it doesn't seem to respond to any input at all. I click on the UI touch screen or the keyboard/home/menu buttons etc and the Android Emulator just doesn't respond.  I can't even open the browser or do anything.  Could anyone suggest what the problem might be?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me the settings for your avd (Android virtual device)? I assume you have tried recreating it from scratch too?

Comment: Also i really suggest you try to set up one of the x86 emulator images, the arm emulation is really slow and in my experience more buggy than the arm images. You will also want to install HAXM to speed it up even more and enable GPU acceleration. Lastly I always give it some SDCard space. http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html If for some reason none of this works for you, you might want to give http://androvm.org/blog/ a try.

Comment: @PaulHarris Here are the settings for my AVD. Note that I get the same behaviour for 2 avd's I set up (one for 2.2 and one for 4.1.2):

`hw.lcd.density=240
hw.screen=touch
skin.name=WVGA800
skin.path=platforms/android-8/skins/WVGA800
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi
hw.keyboard=yes
vm.heapSize=24
image.sysdir.1=platforms/android-8/images/`

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when I enable GPU acceleration. Not ideal, but disabling that should fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried including Zepto.js instead of the standard Javascript Library instead of the normal Jquery.js file?

It is much faster for response since it is a lighter package that shines on the slow Android Emulator.

For testing your Click Events and to speed up the click response, include fastclick.js from fwebdev

If both do not work, try Dolphin Browser : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&hl=en

https://gist.github.com/2168307

```
//======================================================== FASTCLICK
function FastButton(element, handler) {
    this.element = element;
    this.handler = handler;
    element.addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
};
FastButton.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
       case 'touchstart': this.onTouchStart(event); break;
       case 'touchmove': this.onTouchMove(event); break;
       case 'touchend': this.onClick(event); break;
       case 'click': this.onClick(event); break;
    }
 };
FastButton.prototype.onTouchStart = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.element.addEventListener('touchend', this, false);
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', this, false);
    this.startX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    this.startY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    isMoving = false;
 };
FastButton.prototype.onTouchMove = function(event) {
    if(Math.abs(event.touches[0].clientX - this.startX) > 10 || Math.abs(event.touches[0].clientY - this.startY) > 10) {
       this.reset();
    }
 };
FastButton.prototype.onClick = function(event) {
    this.reset();
    this.handler(event);
    if(event.type == 'touchend') {
       preventGhostClick(this.startX, this.startY);
    }
 };
FastButton.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.element.removeEventListener('touchend', this, false);
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', this, false);
};
function preventGhostClick(x, y) {
    coordinates.push(x, y);
    window.setTimeout(gpop, 2500);
};
function gpop() {
    coordinates.splice(0, 2);
};
function gonClick(event) {
    for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i += 2) {
       var x = coordinates[i];
       var y = coordinates[i + 1];
       if(Math.abs(event.clientX - x) < 25 && Math.abs(event.clientY - y) < 25) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
       }
    }
};
document.addEventListener('click', gonClick, true);
var coordinates = [];
function initFastButtons() {
    new FastButton(document.getElementById("fastclick"), goSomewhere);
};
function goSomewhere() {
    var theTarget = document.elementFromPoint(this.startX, this.startY);
    if(theTarget.nodeType == 3) theTarget = theTarget.parentNode;
    var theEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    theEvent.initEvent('click', true, true);
    theTarget.dispatchEvent(theEvent);
};
//========================================================

//When using jQuery call init on domReady-Event
$(document).ready(function() {
initFastButtons();
})
```

Comment: It's the actual Android Emulator that's not responding to any input at all. I can't even get open the Android browser to test my app yet.  So the problem isn't related to the toolkit/library I'm using. It's an issue with the Android Emulator itself.

Comment: came here for the same problem got some jquery shill

Comment: @eyurdakul You do realize that this post was 10 years ago and would have no bearing on modern development, right?